# Using custom post types WordPress network

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, database, google-maps

Working on a project I am setting up a WordPress network containing sites/blogs for small shops. I would like to use 2 custom post types in the following way:

A location post type; The blog admin can change/add a location, which is picked by a Google Maps plugin and inserted in the main blog Google Maps (which can searched and so on...)

A sale post type; the blog admin can change/add a sale item, which should be randomly shown on main blog and around relevant Google Maps results.

I have been searching for an answer weither this is possible for over a week now. But I just can't believe that this is impossible to realize.

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

EDIT to clarify: I would like every site admin to add these post types and then be able to display them on the network main site.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible but as written this question is essentially asking someone to write a moderately complicated plugin with insufficient detail about functionality. I am not even sure that a CPT is what you need.

Comment: I need one custom post type to take an adress, opening hours and description, the other one should take an image, price and discription. I thought that it would be better to use a CPT rather than custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar for a client. I found it easiest to create my custom post types as part of a plugin and network activate it. Without reinventing the wheel, I used a plugin from WPMU Dev to show those posts on the main site. If creating the custom post type isn't your forte, WPMU Dev has a plugin that will help you with creating them.

[WPMU Dev Recent Posts](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/recent-posts/)
[WPMU Dev CustomPress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/custompress/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick for me.